# Error when installing module 'message' (AttributeError: module 'message' has no attribute '__all__')

Tags: python, module, attributeerror, python-3.7

I get the following error when I try to install Python module 'message':

> AttributeError: module 'message' has no attribute '__all__'[image]

I would appreciate if someone could help with this problem. Thank you in advance.

Comment: I have no answer for you, but I can confirm that I'm seeing the exact same error, on Fedora 30.

Answer (score 0):

Might be a little late to anwser but maybe this will help.
I was getting a similar error message when I was trying to import some modules. The error was:

```
AttributeError: module 'xxx' has no attribute '__all__'
```

What I found on the Python issue tracker was this:

> That's because there is also a standard library module named token (https://docs.python.org/3/library/token.html).  When you run python, by default the current working directory is inserted at the beginning of sys.path, the list of directories searched for modules.  If you have a file there that has the same name as a standard library module, e.g. token.py, it will be found first and, thus, "hide" the standard library module of the same name.  Either change the name of your file so it does not conflict or make sure it is in a directory not on sys.path.

So the problem here might be that python tries to import a 'message.py' module while you also have a different 'message.py' file somewhere else in your directory.